# Proof for $\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{(1+a^3)(1+b^3)}} + \frac{b^2}{\sqrt{(1+b^3)(1+c^3)}} + \frac{c^2}{\sqrt{(1+c^3)(1+a^3)}} \geq \frac{4}{3}$?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

> Let $a, b, c$ be real numbers such that $abc=8$. Prove that: $$\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{(1+a^3)(1+b^3)}} + \frac{b^2}{\sqrt{(1+b^3)(1+c^3)}} + \frac{c^2}{\sqrt{(1+c^3)(1+a^3)}} \geq \frac{4}{3}$$

Possible Solution:

> $\sqrt{1+k^3} = \sqrt{(1+k)(1-k+k^2)} \stackrel{AM-GM}{\leq} \frac{k^2-k+1+k+1}{2} = \frac{k^2+2}{2} (*)$ Thus: 
>   $$\begin{equation} \begin{split} \displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{(1+a^3)(1+b^3)}} & \geq \frac{4}{3} \\
> \stackrel{(*)}{\Rightarrow} \sum_{cyc} \frac{4a^2}{(a^2+2)(b^2+2)} & \geq \frac{4}{3} \\
> \Rightarrow 3 \sum_{cyc} a^2(c^2+2) & \geq (a^2+2)(b^2+2)(c^2+2) \\ 
> \Rightarrow \sum_{cyc} 2a^2+ \sum_{cyc} a^2b^2 & \geq 72 \end{split} \end{equation}$$
>   Which is true by applying AM-GM in both sums separately. Hence proved.

The above solution states that $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \frac{4a^2}{(a^2+2)(b^2+2)} \geq \sum_{cyc} \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{(1+a^3)(1+b^3)}}$

So it proves that $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \frac{4a^2}{(a^2+2)(b^2+2)} \geq \frac{4}{3}$ instead of $\displaystyle\sum_{cyc} \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{(1+a^3)(1+b^3)}} \geq \frac{4}{3}$

Is that or the solution correct?

Generally if we are being asked to prove that $x \geq y$ and we prove that $z \geq x$, does it suffices to prove that $z \geq y$?

Comment: Generally not valid.  For example, prove that `3>5`.  You claim `10>3` and `10>5`.

Comment: Yeah I know... So the solution is wrong doesn't it?

Comment: You need to show for that $x≥z$ and $z≥y$ for that $z$

Comment: Well...the solution doesn't state that $$ \sum\limits_{cyc}{\frac{4a^2}{\left(a^2+2\right)\left(b^2+2\right)}} \ge \sum\limits_{cyc}{\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{\left(1+a^3\right)\left(1+b^3\right)}}} $$ Instead, it of course means the reverse one!

Comment: As commented above, $$\sqrt{1+k^3} \le \frac{k^2+2}2 \implies \frac1{\sqrt{1+k^3} } \ge \frac2{k^2+2}$$